# Problems building an Sql Server Database Project: comparison, refactoring warnings, etc

Tags: sql, visual-studio, build, msbuild, database-project

A colleague of mine is having problems building a Sql Server Database Project in [visual-studio-2013](/questions/tagged/visual-studio-2013). He shared his screen with me, hoping I could help him solve the following issues:

[image]

In case you can't see the image, there's a build error stating that "The comparison cannot continue until the build error is resolved" and a build warning that goes "Refactoring operations exist in the source, but will not be shown in the comparison.".

Not being too familiar with Sql Server DB projects, I tried searching the exact same messages on Google... only to find absolutely nothing.

Can anyone help? What does these messages means, why are they appearing and how can we expect to successfully build the project?

Answer (score 0):

I had this same issue but it went away when I followed the instructions of the accepted answer of this post: [VS2013 Database Project fails to build](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774471/vs2013-database-project-fails-to-build).

It turns out that the project was not building.  The error described in this post was misleading and was probably only a symptom of the real error which was that the project could no build.

In case that link is no longer available, the solution was to install the [Microsoft SQL Server Data Tools](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/tools.aspx).  You can do that by downloading the install package [from here](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=393521&clcid=0x409).