# Visual Studio 2013 SQL Server database project build failure

Tags: sql, sql-server, visual-studio-2013, sql-server-data-tools

I'm playing with a SQL Server database project with Visual Studio 2013 on Windows 2012 R2. Below is my code and you can download the whole project source code from my shared dropbox link at https://www.dropbox.com/s/aalnlwvxutr4g0f/UDF.zip?dl=1

```
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;
using System.Data.SqlTypes;
using Microsoft.SqlServer.Server;

public partial class UserDefinedFunctions
{
    [Microsoft.SqlServer.Server.SqlFunction]
    public static SqlString Greetings(SqlString name)
    {
        // Put your code here
        return new SqlString("Hello " + (string)name);
    }
}
```

When I try to build the solution, I got the following message.

> ------ Build started: Project: UDF, Configuration: Debug Any CPU ------
>       Creating a model to represent the project...
>   Done building project "UDF.sqlproj" -- FAILED.
>
> Build FAILED.
>   ========== Build: 0 succeeded or up-to-date, 1 failed, 0 skipped ==========

Essentially it tells me the build failed but I can't find any specific errors. Also there is nothing listed under the Error List pane. Please point me the right direction?

Comment: Have you looked at this related question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25774471/vs2013-database-project-fails-to-build

Comment: Works on my system with all the latest versions installed.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to install the last version of SQL Server Data Tools
here is the link

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/data/hh297027

http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=393521&clcid=0x409

after install restart computer and try to build again.

Comment: Thank you a million Imran! I've upgraded my SSDT from 12.0.41012.0 to 12.0.50226.0 and it fixed my problem.