# Running Batch Script on Remote Server

Tags: c#, powershell, batch-file, process

I'm tasked with automating an internal process.
This process involves first being logged on a remote server (A).
From server A, a user would connect to Remote Server (B).

Once authenticated onto Server B, the C# application needs to run a batch file

I've used some sample code form a post on [CodeProject](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/43705/Remote-Desktop-using-C-NET) to make all the remote desktop connections through some GUI and it's working without issue.
The codes uses the [ActiveX MSTSC Library](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa383022(v=vs.85).aspx).

I then sue this block of code, hoping to start the Batch File:

```
    private void button3_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            //PowerShell ps = PowerShell.Create();
            //ps.AddCommand("Start-Process");
            //ps.AddArgument("/c c:\\Recycle.bat");
            //ps.Invoke();

            Process p = new Process();
            p.StartInfo.FileName = "C://Recycle.bat";
            p.StartInfo.CreateNoWindow = false;
            p.Start();
        }

        catch(Exception exception)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(exception.Message);
        }
    }
```

I've tried using the PowerShell class, as well as the System.Diagnostics.Process objects.
The PS object yeilds "no file found", where
the process objects executes the "Recycle.bat" script on my ***local computer, not the remote server.***

How would you attach the Process object to the remote server and not my local PC?

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Any reason why you can't just use winrs to run the remote batch file? EG `winrs -r:(remote sserver hostname) c:\recycle.bat`

Comment: This application is being developed as an easy GUI to be used by an internal team.

Eventually, the application should have a checklist of servers, where the users ticks off the servers to "recycle" and clicks run.

Comment: Ah. So if it a gui based thing in C# then see this thread: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/428276/how-to-execute-a-command-in-a-remote-computer but if you want it to work through powershell, then try this link: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9535515/powershell-execute-remote-exe-with-command-line-arguments-on-remote-computer

Comment: Thank you for your Reply Tim, It's much appreciated!
I'll look into both methods now.

Answer (score 1):

There is something called WMI. Try the following URL 
http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/18146/How-To-Almost-Everything-In-WMI-via-C-Part-Proce

Comment: Yes, WMI would work too, but the code to create a shell object to run winrs (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1469764/run-command-prompt-commands) is much lighter (3 lines) than the code to run a remote process through WMI (~20?). However, it may be more aesthetically pleasing to use WMI since you won't have a black dos window popping up briefly.

Comment: I agree with you. But it was mentioned as GUI so I suggested this option

Comment: It seems the link you provided is outdated.
May you provide another example to follow?

Comment: Don't judge that by UI. You can customize your UI and the code for core logic is available.

Comment: Thanks,

But I cannot find the "baileysoft.WMI.process" reference which is being used in the article.

Comment: Read the last part of article. Bailey soft is not a reference