# Remote Powershell script causes Selenium to timeout

Tags: powershell, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, powershell-remoting

When I use `Invoke-Command` from a Powershell script to run an *.exe* that uses *Selenium Chromedriver*, the execution of my *.exe* hangs until I get a timeout exception.

I have tried running the *.exe* with a local Powershell command, and it works just fine every time. It is only when I use `Invoke-Command` that the *.exe* stops working. Is there any way to actually run powershell scripts remotely, without `Invoke-Command` because `Invoke-Command` doesn't seem to be doing what I want it to.

I've also tried to `-Wait` the process of the *.exe* but it still hangs.

Comment: Maybe try something here: [Powershell execute remote exe](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9535737/10350118)

Comment: Can you post entire error