# Use DevOps Release Pipeline to Upload Artifacts to a Linux Server

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

Is there a simple way to upload build artifacts in a zip file to a Linux Server using SCP or some other protocol?

Right now the build sits in a specific directory on the build server ready to be uploaded but the docs I've been reading haven't made it clear how to upload it to Linux using DevOps Release Pipeline.  The documentation and question/answers I've been reading appears to be windows to windows rather than windows to Linux.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is there a simple way to upload build artifacts in a zip file to a Linux Server using SCP or some other protocol?

You could try to use [Copy Files Over SSH](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/deploy/copy-files-over-ssh?view=azure-devops) task to copy the Artifacts to a Linux Server.

> Use this task in a build or release pipeline to copy files from a
> source folder to a target folder on a remote machine over SSH.
>
> This task allows you to connect to a remote machine using SSH and copy
> files matching a set of minimatch patterns from specified source
> folder to target folder on the remote machine. Supported protocols for
> file transfer are SFTP and **SCP** via SFTP. **In addition to Linux**, macOS
> is partially supported.

Please check the developer forum [Copy Files Over SSH during Continuous Integration and Deployment](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/devops/copy-files-over-ssh-during-continuous-integration-and-deployment/) for some more details.

Comment: This works.  In release, I just need to specify a new task and use the SSH configuration.  The build is in the wrong configuration though so I have to figure that out in the build pipeline but I think we're getting close to a continuous integration and deployment solution.  Thanks Leo!